# How to find nth parent element using element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a following dom code

```
<div id='parent1' class="test">
    <br/>
    <div id='parent2'>
        <br/> <span><p id='element1'>Test</p></span>
        <br/>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id='parent3'>
        <br/> <span><p id='element2'>Test</p></span>
        <br/>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <p>JavascriptDevelopers</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
</div>
```

I written an event,it returns the following element as a target element.

```
 <p>JavascriptDevelopers</p>
```

using This element, I want to find `parentElement`,which has classname `test`.For this I searched in Google.I found the following code.

```
$("#element2").closest('.test').attr("id")
```

it's working fine with `id`,the problem was in my case the element doesn't have any attributes like `id,class`.So I tried the following way but it's not working.

```
var domEle=event.target(reference:<p>JavascriptDevelopers</p>);
domEle.closest('.test').attr("id");
```

can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
$(event.target).closest('.test').attr("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

$(event.target).closest('.test').attr("id");

Answer (score 0):

You can try with wrapping the dom node in jQuery wrapper:

```
var domEle=event.target(reference:<p>JavascriptDevelopers</p>);
$(domEle).closest('.test').attr("id");
```

Or a more jQuery way:

```
$(event.target).closest('.test').attr('id');
```

or this:

```
 $(event.target).closest('.test')[0].id;
```

---

In your code seems that you are attaching a jQuery method to a dom node, instead you have to wrap it up with jQuery.